# Convert varchar as date to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, casting

I have a varchar value `04 Jul 2016 12:00:00 AM`.

How can I convert it to `2016-07-04`?

Comment: Write a query using `Cast` function

Comment: Also *TAG* the `RDBMS` you are using since `Date` functions are specific to database engine

Comment: `To_Date(MyField, 'DD MON YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')` in case of *Oracle*

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple conversion. Assuming you are on SQL Server as per your previous questions.

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (OldDate varchar(30))
INSERT INTO #TestData
VALUES ('04 Jul 2016 12:00:00 AM')
```

Query

```
SELECT
OldDate
,CONVERT(date,OldDate) NewDate
FROM #TestData
```

Result

```
OldDate                     NewDate
04 Jul 2016 12:00:00 AM     2016-07-04
```

You can also use `CAST` in place of `CONVERT` to get the same result

```
SELECT
OldDate
,CAST(OldDate AS date) NewDate
FROM #TestData
```

Comment: This assumes OP is using `SQL SERVER`

Comment: Sure, as per the OP's previous questions which are SQL Server and SSIS questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (OldDate varchar(30))
INSERT INTO #TestData
VALUES ('04 Jul 2016 12:00:00 AM')
```

Then

```
SELECT OldDate = CAST (OldDate AS DATE) FROM #TestData
```

OR

```
SELECT convert(date, OldDate, 102)FROM #TestData
```